# sql server connection error - no such host is known

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have installed **SQL server 2017** on my VPS that I have access on over IP.
I have set up a port for the server and also have given access to that port in the firewall.

now I am trying to add this server to my Visual Studio 2017  using `"add data connection"` command in server explorer, but after giving the server name as **" tcp:XX.XX.XX.XX,port"** and username and password that I have created over SQL server,  an error message occures:

> " TCP provider, no such host is known"

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Df8.jpg)

Comment: I guess the server name has to be given without the "tcp:" at the beginning... did you try this?

Comment: @Tyron78 serve is not in my local network, it has a static IP.
can it find my server name when i just typed it down without IP address??

Comment: I meant without tcp, not without IP. Like the following: ` XX.XX.XX.XX,port'

Comment: @Tyron78 it did not worked also

Comment: i did dis already exactly with "tcp:ipadress,port"
but it does not work now

Comment: can you ping the IP?

Comment: @Tyron78 no actually, and this is confusing me. because i am connected to this VPS via RDP. but ping request returns " Request timed out."

Comment: Maybe this is of use to you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: I did all the steps in this article,

Comment: Now error message is changed to " connection wait timed out"